# Convert query with cursor to more optimized methodology

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with many columns but two of them that are of interest in this case. One of the columns represents a subversion commit numnber, and the other one prepresents a timestamp of when an automated process ran using the data from the aforementioned commit number. Theres many rows with the same commit number, and any number greater than or equal to 1 of the timestamp. I need to get a list of distinct commit numbers, and the earliest timestamp in the table for each one.

I can do this with a cursor that iterates between the distinct commit numbers, and finds the top 1 timestamp for each commit, but this is very slow because there are 56 million rows in the table. I feel certain there must be a more efficient way.

Below you can see my TSql.

```
DECLARE @CommitDates TABLE (CommitNumber int, LastUpdate date)
declare @commit int

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT [CommitNumber] FROM ProcessHistory ORDER BY [CommitNumber] DESC

OPEN db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @commit

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @CommitDates ([CommitNumber], [LastUpdate]) 
    select top 1 [CommitNumber],LastUpdate from ProcessHistory WHERE [CommitNumber]=@commit ORDER BY LastUpdate ASC
    fetch next from db_cursor into @commit
END
CLOSE db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
SELECT * from @CommitDates
```

Expected results: be able to know quickly what the first date a given commit number appears in the table without having to pull up the subversion log viewer. In this case, i would define "quickly" as executing in no more than 60 seconds.

Actual results: it takes more than 7 minutes 30 seconds to execute this code which returns only 176 rows as of today.

Answer (score 0):

Well i feel silly, just figured it out:

SELECT [CommitNumber],MIN([LastUpdate]) FROM ProcessHistory GROUP BY [CommitNumber]

Executes in literally 00:00:02